# How to read SSL certificate details programmatically (possibly c#) if website is getting redirected to another

Tags: ssl

I am trying to read SSL certificate details programmatically but as the my destination website is getting redirected to another one. I am getting certificate details of the redirected website but not the which I am trying to access.

How can I read certificate details of the website which are getting redirected to another one?

Comment: Don't follow the redirection then... The TLS stuff is happening before the HTTP redirection, so the client gets all the TLS related data, including server certificate before getting the HTTP redirections status code and the `location` header with the new URL to follow.

Answer (score 0):

After the research, I am able to get this information by simply adding below line in the code.

```
request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
```

Complete sample code is as below-

```
  public static List<CerDetails> GetList(List<string> domainList)
    {
        List<CerDetails> cerList = new List<CerDetails>();
        foreach (var domain in domainList)
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(domain);
            request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            response.Close();

            X509Certificate cert = request.ServicePoint.Certificate;
            X509Certificate2 cert2 = new X509Certificate2(cert);

            CerDetails cer = new CerDetails();
            cer.Domain = domain;
            cer.Issuer = cert2.Issuer;
            cer.Thumbprint = cert2.Thumbprint;
            cer.Subject = cert2.Subject;
            cer.SerialNumber = cert2.SerialNumber;
            cer.IssuedDate = cert2.GetEffectiveDateString();
            cer.ExpiryDate = cert2.GetExpirationDateString();
            cerList.Add(cer);
        }
        return cerList;
    }
```

Comment: For a good question on this website you should have added your code in your question because otherwise noone knows how you contact servers... But it is great you put a proper answer to your own question, don't forget to mark it as accepted later.